# How i can install android studio 2.2 in ubuntu 18

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, installation

I have Linux (Ubuntu 18)

i want to install android 2.2 but

when go to this link

[Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio)

**only have latest version not found 2.2**

How i found version 2.2 and download to ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking at the main downloads page you need to go to the archive. However, the oldest version they have there is 2.3.2.

https://developer.android.com/studio/archive